# Set progressbar position of swiperefreshlayout

Tags: android

Is there a simple way to change the position of swiperefreshlayouts progressbar. I would like to add some yTranslation to the progressbar tomset the positionbbelow a transparent actionbar (Swiperefreahlayout is behind actionbar). However it turns out, that swiperefreshlayout dont use a progressbar (or any other kind of View) but rather draws directly on the canvas of swipebacklayout. so the only way is to copy the code from swiperefreshlayout, right? Or does someone else knows a better workaround?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it correctly, you're using:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="(A PARENT THEME WITH ACTION_BAR">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

in your Theme, right? (or `<item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>` if you're supporting Android 2.+ too)

If you are using the area below (in z-axis) the `ActionBar` for other views and want the Progress indicator of the `SwipeRefreshLayout` to be right after the `ActionBar` (in y-axis), them just add a `PaddingTop` to the `ListView` in the `SwipeRefreshLayout`. For example:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize" >
    </ListView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

or `?attr/actionBarSize` if you're supporting Android 2.+ too.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work - at least for me. The progress bar is then under the action bar. I also tried some other attempts without good results.

Comment: @cybergen I'm sorry for the delay to answer you, but did you manage it to work? If not, I could submit a demo project in my GitHub profile exemplifying what I tried to answer in my post above.

Comment: The progress bar implementation of SwipeRefreshLayout has changed and  now it looks good. Furthermore I don't use an ActionBar but a ToolBar now. All problems are solved. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Fast scroll in recyclerveiew was added in api 26.
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions#26-0-0.

If you want to use it pre api 26 use

https://github.com/L4Digital/FastScroll

This library has builtin fastscroll and it has a scroll listener that can disable the refreshview layout on scrolling

The developer addresses the problem here:

https://github.com/L4Digital/FastScroll/issues/14